# Function or filter vs computed attribute with css class name

Tags: angularjs

I have a user object and I have a complex logic, that I want to unit test, which takes a user object and decides how it should be displayed - which css class should be used.

There are two approach that I consider:

```
<td class="{{ user | classify }}">
```

or

```
<td class="{{ user.cssClass }}"><!-- or --><td ng-class="user.cssClass">
```

or

```
<td ng-class="computeCssClass(user)">
```

The first approach assumes I create a filter that based on the provided user objects returns the css class.

The second approach assumes I add a new attribute `cssClass` to the model and whenever a new user object is created (fetched from the REST API) I compute the `cssClass` attribute.

The third approach assumes I create a function which computes the css class for the provided user object.

What are the pros and cons of the above three approaches?

---

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLzro2h1/) to play with these three approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only significant difference I can think of is around the **data-binding**

### 1st approach, using filter

```
<td class="{{ user | classify }}">
```

**Pro:** leverage angular's powerful filter mechanism, shorter and nicer syntax

**Con:** a `$watch` will be put on the `user` object to watch for changes, and then call the `filter`, which actually loop through `$filterProvider` to find the correct `provider` function and execute it (I guess you'll figure out the overhead implication of this process)

### 2nd approach, using object's property

```
<td class="{{ user.cssClass }}"><!-- or --><td ng-class="user.cssClass">
```

**Pro:** just a normal 2-way binding (the magic of Angular JS), and you are doing it in the Angular-way

**Con:** not really a "con", this approach leverage automatic 2-way binding, which is a `$watch` on the user object's property to watch for changes, and update the class attribute

### 3rd approach

```
<td ng-class="computeCssClass(user)">
```

**Pro:** You have more control of when the class attribute got updated (by the return value of the function)

**Con:** it's easier to mess things up. **[Edited]** Overhead of `$watch` a function: the function is executed multiple times in a `$digest` and its return value got comparing to watch for changes, can be expensive.

<del>If performance is what you care about most, the **3rd approach** would be a good choice for you.</del>

If you want to use `ng-class`, of all the above approaches, the **2nd approach** will have the least overhead.

You can consider one-time binding, or a custom directive to handle updating class attributes. If you use the "class" attribute, you will be able to leverage the one-time binding syntax:

```
<td class="{{ ::user.cssClass }}">
```

Pre-compiling some presentation attributes from the data is always good, unless you have very specific requirement such as *changing the user's dashboard background colour/image basing on the current weather of his/her location* (well, even with this requirement, the weather is what should be `$watch` for)

I saw that you compute the `class` on a `<td>`. It's very easy to reach to the number of `$watch` that slows the page down significantly with table (read the 2nd answer of the referenced question above)

Anyway, it's all up to you which approach should you use, basing on the real-world context of the application you are developing.

Comment: Thanks Duc Nguyen for the answer, but isn't the 3rd approach using the same $watch on the user object as the 1fst approach? The 2nd solution puts $watch on `user.cssClass`, while 1st and 3rd on the complete `user` object, is that correct?

Comment: Thanks @AdamSiemion for your comment. You are correct about the watch. I have updated my answer. The watch in 3rd approach is a watch for a function, which has more overhead that watching for object property.

Answer (score 1):

This could use `ng-class` it self with an expression.

```
<td ng-class="{ active: user.active, suspended: user.suspended }">
```

Or if you are passing the `cssClass` directly from the API then that would be more easier

```
<td ng-class="user.cssClass">
```

**Edit**

1st Approach

---

**Pros:** Will give you desired output :)

**Cons**

1. In your 1st approach by creating filter you are going to return css class name from it. Theoretically it will work, but if you think technically filter is mostly used on the `collection` object to filter out data based on filter criteria.
2. Also using `attribute` with the `{{}}` wouldn't make sense to evaluate a class value, as angular does provide `ng-class` which is dedicated to do it.

### 2nd Approach

It looks pretty good. but in this you need to refactor your code bit. By moving it to `utilService` & lets use that code for `ng-class` directive by calling method from controller.

**HTML**

```
<td ng-class="cssClassComputationCode()">
```

**Service**

```
app.service('utilService', function(){
    var self = this;
    //below method can be testable by injecting its dependency in testing module
    self.cssClassComputationCode = function(){
        var cssClass = '';
        //here the computation thing will happen 
        cssClass = 'active';
        //some more code
        return cssClass;
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, utilService){
     //assigning service method reference to controller scope variable
     $scope.computeCssClass = utilService.cssClassComputationCode;

     //other code here

});
```

Comment: I do not want to use expressions with ng-class because: 1) they will be duplicated in many places in the code, I want the logic that decides how to display a user in once place, 2) the actual logic I have is more complex than just checking the `active` and `suspended` attributes.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I have added this as another possibility. It seems very similar to the filter solution. Can you compare this approach with the second approach? In terms of its impact on the two-way data binding e.g.

Comment: @AdamSiemion still you need any explanation why you shouldn't go for 1st approach?

Comment: yes, please, can you compare the performance implications of the filter or function vs computed attribute solution?